# Add PERMISSION_DENIED Event Error to My Own Logger

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Today I had a function that wouldn't run correctly, and when I checked GCP Log Explorer I saw an error like the following:

```
{
   "jobName":"projects/my-function",
   "url":"https://us-central1-my-domain-dev.cloudfunctions.net/my-function",
   "@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished",
   "status":"PERMISSION_DENIED",
   "targetType":"HTTP"
}
```

I think what happened is something went wrong the last time I deployed this function, so I had to delete it and deploy it again, which disconnected it from its allUsers/Cloud Functions Invoker member.

Since this function runs on a schedule, I don't monitor the logs every time it runs. Is it possible to listen for this type of event and send an alert when it happens so it isn't discovered only after the scheduled job is noticed failing after eg a day or two?

Comment: If "allUsers/Cloud Functions Invoker" was removed, this must mean that it was deployed with an outdated version of the `firebase-tools` CLI (older than 7.7.0, late 2019).

Comment: @samthecodingman I don't understand what you mean?

Answer (score -1):

The logging systems used by Firebase Functions are built on Cloud Logging which is a part of the [Cloud Operations Suite](https://cloud.google.com/products/operations) (formerly known as StackDriver). Like Firebase, it is a billed service that has a free quota. See [Cloud Operations Suite Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing) for more information.

To my knowledge, there is no way for Cloud Logging to issue out alerts from the either the Firebase Console or Google Cloud Consoles in the form of a notification on its own.

It expects that you make use of [Cloud Monitoring metrics](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/counter-metrics) to trigger webhooks or pub/sub topics; or you [route specific logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/routing/overview) to a user-specified sink (such as Google Storage, BigQuery or a pub/sub topic) and monitor where the logs have been sent (like triggering a Cloud Function).

Ultimately, the approach you employ and how you consume the reports is up to you to evaluate and select, this part is beyond the scope of StackOverflow.

In either case, you need to specify a filter for the log messages for the metric or router. To loosely match the log you've provided, you'd at least specify the `@type` and `severity` level of that log entry. It may also be helpful to include/exclude specific reported values for `status`.

```
severity=NOTICE
protoPayload.@type="type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished"
protoPayload.status="PERMISSION_DENIED"
```

**Note:** I'm assuming that this message has a severity of `NOTICE` as you didn't mention it.

Comment: @1252748 I'd say mine was downvoted because my answer is a bit of a non-answer. I don't know about your question but maybe someone thought it wasn't code related enough or too broad for StackOverflow but not enough to close it.